# Best Data Structure to store marks and ranks of students

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have the following information of students with corresponding marks and ranks

```
Name   Marks  Rank
 A      30     1
 B      20     2
 C      10     3
```

The rank of the student is inversely proportional to the marks of the student. I have to find the best data structure to store the above information so that the following operations are executed in the most optimal manner(Best time complexity) . It can be assumed that student name is unique.

1. Given student name , find marks and rank
2. Given rank, find marks and name of the student
3. Update marks of a student.

I am thinking of using two hashmaps one for student and marks mapping and another for student name and rank mapping. Is there a better data structure for this?. Is there a way that i can make use of the fact that rank is inversely proportional to marks.

Comment: Hashmaps are (in average) O(1) for the operation you are looking for, so you can't beat that. Yet, they require space.
What you can do is: Create a class with Name, Marks (? one or many), rank. Then two hashmaps for name and rank that point to the class of that user. Expensive but works.

Comment: Another option would be to have a Comparable class of Name + Marks, a comparison method to sort automatically by rank, and a simple List to store them all. Pros: updating rank is automatic, less space required, code probably easier to read. Cons: slower than hashmaps, access is not o(1) anymore.

Comment: Why not use a `class Student` with fields `name` and `marks` and get the rank by reverse-sorting the list of students by `marks`? You could also add an attribute `rank` that's reset each time the list is sorted.

Comment: Basic lists is not very good for sorting guys. Why sort a list every time, while you could use max heap priority queue or something similar ;-).

Comment: You should use some sort of sorted map, using your class student which again should have fields to store name, marks and rank. This should ideally implement `Comparable` and override `compare` method so the map can compare. I hope `TreeMap` should do.

Comment: @EsseTi The problem with it is updating. Updating a mark of a student influences the rank of ALL students.

Comment: @tobias_k The order might be resetted each update of any grade, for all students.

Comment: If two students have the same marks, how do you rank them? how do you find *one* student by rankt then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with two data structures:

1. A **hash map** that maps from student name to his grade.
2. An **[order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)** of students, where the key for comparisons is the grade.

---

This allows you to do all of the following operations in `O(logn)`:

1. Find a student's rank: find it in the hash map, and then find its order statistic (rank) in the tree.
2. Update a student grade: find his old grade in the map, remove it from both map and tree, and reinsert it again with the new values.
3. Given a rank, use the order statistic tree to find the relevant student and his grade.

In addition, Finding a student's grade is done in `O(1)` (average case) using the hash map alone.

---

Note:

You can switch implementation of the student name->grade map to a tree map rather than hash map without influencing the complexity too much, and guaranteeing better worst case behavior. (Finding a grade will also be O(logn) and not O(1) with this change).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is also to use two `HashMap`, but one of them is filled gradually instead of adding it's sorting complexity to update time. This would provide the following properties:

- fast reading `byStudent`
- slower updates O(n). If you update a lot, you could consider pulling `reorder` out of the `addOrUpdate` method, updating in batches, and calling reorder after each batch from the outside.
- eventually fast `byRank` reading.

---

```
class MyClass {
    Comparator<RankedStudent> comp = Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.marks);
    private Map<String, RankedStudent> repo = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, RankedStudent> rankCache = new HashMap<>();

    public RankedStudent getByStudent(String student) {
        return repo.get(student);
    }

    public RankedStudent getByRank(Integer rank) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(rankCache.get(rank)).orElseGet(() -> {
            rankCache.putIfAbsent(rank, repo.values().stream().sorted((s1, s2) -> rank == s1.rank ? 1 : 0)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null));
            return rankCache.get(rank);
        });
    }

    public void addOrUpdate(String student, Integer marks) {
        repo.put(student, new RankedStudent(student, marks, -1));
        reorder();
    }

    public void reorder() {
        final Iterator<RankedStudent> it = repo.values().stream().sorted(comp.reversed()).iterator();
        IntStream.range(0, repo.size()).boxed().forEach(i -> it.next().rank = i + 1);
        rankCache.clear();
    }
}

class RankedStudent {

    public String name;
    public int marks;
    public int rank;

    public RankedStudent(String name, int marks, int rank) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
}
```